# Relations between Requests and Threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, request

In ASP.NET (Web API 2 + OWIN, if this matters), if a new request is received, will a new thread be created?

I am asking this question since I have several utility classes which modify properties in my entities. I am not sure whether I need to implement a `lock` when I am modifying my objects.

```
// Controller endpoint
[HttpPut]
[Route("update/order")]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateOrder(OrderDTO dto)
{
    OrderContext orderContext = new OrderContext();
    Order entity = orderContext.Orders.Single(e => e.Id == dto.Id);

    OrderUtil.UpdateOrder(entity, dto);
    orderContext.SaveChanges();

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}

// OrderUtil.UpdateSomething function
public static void UpdateOrder(Order entity, OrderDTO dto)
{
    // Do I need a lock here?
    lock (padlock)
    {
        entity.Status = dto.Status;
        entity.DeliveryDate = dto.DeliveryDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a request arrives, a thread is picked from the ThreadPool to service the request. If there is not a thread and the maximum threads of the ThreadPool is not reached, a thread is created.

This is still considered multi-threaded, all requests being processed on the server are on different threads => the shared resources can still be modified by multi-threads at the same time.

Therefore, `lock` is required if you need to control concurrent access to the shared resources. But if the resource is Sql, you should leave the locking to Sql server.

**Update based on updated question:**

With your code, you don't need to `lock` because you create a different `OrderContext` for each thread and you pass in different `entity` and `orderDto`. These objects are not shared between threads. If you're concerned about concurrency control for your data, this should be handled using transaction, Db locks, timestamp,.... instead of c# locks.

Comment: @Aldour Cheng: For sure that 2 separate requests being processed by the server are on different threads, so you need a lock.

Comment: Should all endpoints be wrapped by `lock` except for the `GET` ones? But then there will be `lock` everywhere...

Comment: @Aldour Cheng: a good design for multi-threaded enviroment is to avoid shared resources (static) as much as possible.

Comment: As long as your context is unique to each thread then you aren't using the same objects in each call.  SQL will handle the locking of the updates at the table level.   Generally you don't want a static entity context hanging around, not sure if thats what your doing here though.

Comment: You should leave the locking to SQL. Investigate versioning alternatives if you're having issues with overwriting stale rows. Don't throw locks everywhere in your application.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead: besides sql server, he may have other in-memory shared resources because concurrency control is not only about Sql server. In these cases, `lock` is still valid.

Comment: @KhanhTO Without seeing the declaration/scoping of the `orderContext` in the OP's code .. its hard to know if thats really the question :/